How can I mask all tables for all Transformation in Job?
In my Pentaho Data Integration (PDI) workflows, I need to copy data from Database A to Database B. so I use copy tables function to do it. copy tables function
However, before writing the data to Database B, I need to mask sensitive information. The problem is that I have to manually add a "Replace in String" step with a regular expression and field type for each of my 300+ transformations.
transformations
have any way I can do the masking in Job? like add the JavaScript or other before transformationJob

To continue your idea, you can modularize your ETL project. You may create a job that call two transformation in a sequence. One transformation can pass parameters to the next one, so you can do this way.
Another thing is that you can crypography files (in job context) or you can cryptografphy stream lines (in transformation context).
The last consideration is that you can replicate the database using the database infraestructe itself, there are more eficient ways to do that, instead using ETL to take this responsability.
You can evolve your ETL using design patthern lik medalion. Hope i could help.

Might be me misreading, but i think he knows how to do it, he just doesn't want to do it 300+ times. He also doesn't want to encrypt all fields, only the sensitive ones. In all methodes mentioned above he still needs to do it 300+ times or everything is scrambled? Or am I missing something.

I think your best solution (especially if you need to do this more often) is to make use of metadata injection based on infrastructure files of the database. For example load a list of tables and fields per table in pentaho, and feed this in a metadata injection process where you have a table read and write function. In between, (or even in the read SQL) you can push a encryption step which encrypts the data if the field is present in a certain list (or even better store the list in a database).
This way you just have to write the metadata injection once, and fill the "to be scrambled" list once. and then you can run the process on the whole database at once, and asa often as you want.
